Clean CSV file using ML
I would like to build a Neural Network to clean a CSV file that contains wrong delimeters.
My approach is the following:

Identify rows that have more columns than the header. Define these rows as "bad rows". Then we have that, for bad row in bad rows: len(bad row) > len(header)
Merge every two columns next to each other in bad row. Do that until: len(bad row) == len(header). Define these rows as "candidate rows".
Based on the "good rows", make a clustering algorithm that finds the row among "candidate rows" that is closest in some sense to the good rows.

My question is the following:

How to create meaningfull features out of the candidate rows and good rows?
Will this approach work. My goal is to solve it using ML, even though this isn't neccesarily the smartest apprach.

Thanks in advance.
